# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angularjs

When i try to Update my database from Mvc-AngularJs to wcf-Rest i'm getting error as  `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   http://localhost:9706/EmployeeService.svc/UpdatexyzData/Update/`  but with the same ur when i try to hit from Fidler Its working fine

**Service.Js**

```
this.xmlDataUpdate = function (sss) {

        var ss = $http({
            url: RestApi+"/UpdatexyzData/Update/",
            method: "PUT",
            data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(sss),
            headers: {
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded ;charset=utf-8'
            }
        })
        return ss;
    }
```

Comment: is your request in json format ?

Comment: yes its in Json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable cors by creating a global.asax file on wcf service,

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u soo much 4r ur value feedBack

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json ;charset=utf-8'
```

And to disable preflight request

> ```
> app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
>   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
>   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
>   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
>   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
> });
> ```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9706/EmployeeService.svc/UpdatexyzData/Update/. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Comment: you must also add access controll allow origin to your server side code

Comment: for .net here is the way of doing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328995/response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-400-aspx

Comment: I did all the changes Even no use i'm getting the same issue

Comment: do you make request like from aa.com to bb.com ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134249/discussion-between-md-dastageerjob-and-salih-senol-cakarci).

Comment: I don't have tw sorry.  you may share your request information and response information from chrome dev tool